# Can a program in C generate and call a bashscript in background and even parsing arguments?

Tags: c, bash, parsing, background-process

Can a program in C generate a bashscript, and use some arguments from the C program to parse arguments to run the bashscript in background mode (without user noticing if really underground its not possible), so I can use some "cool" functions of bashscript to do some job in "C"? I **need the result** of bashscript coming back to the C program.

Thanks in any advice.

Comment: If more information is needed, just ask for it.

Comment: oh, and anyway, this is a cool tool project.

Comment: and to be perfect, yes, I DO need the results of bashscript coming back to C program... =D

Comment: Yes, this is possible, though I would never recommend it. Are you familiar with `fork`/`exec`?

Comment: Some little more talk about arguments coming in/out would be highly appreciated too. Sorry, mistake corrected in question. Thanks.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by arguments "coming out", but to supply the arguments to the script you can just list them after the name of the script like you would in bash (this applies to all the functions suggested: `system`, `exec`).

Comment: arguments coming out was bad. Its the output of the bashscript turning  into a variable inside C program. Question was edited.

Answer (score 2):

Use `fork()` to create a 'clone' of you process.

If you want the results from bash (or whatever other command you will exec) use `pipe()` and `dup()` to create a connection between processes from the standard output (and standard error if you want that too) of the exec'd command. Your process will be able to read (and write if you create more pipes) exec'd programs  output text.

Normally the 'clone' process either use `dup()` to reconnect standard input/output/error onto pipe's, or closes standard standard input/output/error to prevent the exec'd program interacting with the user.

Then use one of the forms of `exec()`.

If you're process does **not** `wait()` the exec'd process will run 'in the background', actually concurrently. The effect of being in the background is mainly the result of being disconnected from the terminal (keyboard and window).

If the pipe's are set up correctly, your program will be able to talk to the fork+exec'd process, but it is easy to get dead-lock, so I suggest you limit your self to reading its output.

Comment: You should be able to find tutorials on the net using the names of those system calls, and that basic flow. I taught this in the '80's on UNIX, and there were papers and books which gave complete answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `system()` command can do the job if you specify the `&` parameter to the scipt process.

The argument of the `system()` should be the command you want to execute, just as if you have executed it from bash.  In this case it would be `script.sh &`, where the `&` tells the operatinf system to run the process in the background.

Note that the use of `system` is operating system dependent and can be insecure, so use it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the `exec` function and variants ? Basically, it replaces the current process with another, according to what you're supplying. I suggest reading the manpages, because there's quite a bit to know about those functions. But I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: `exec()` does not create another process. It replaces the current process.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library system() function may help. An example might look like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ){
    int scriptResult;
    scriptResult = system("myscript.sh");
    return 0;
}
```

There are probably better, more portable solutions to your problem, however because [the behavior changes from platform to platform.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/)

Comment: what about parsing the arguments? Its possible here?

Comment: _Once the command execution has terminated, the processor gives the control back to the program, returning an int value, whose interpretation is system-dependent._  hmm.. Like I suspected, the hole of the white rabbit go far down away...

Answer (score 0):

Working example on Linux. change /bin/bash to your own bash location

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int plumbing( const char * work, char * results, size_t so_results) {
        int p1[2],p2[2];
        pid_t pid,pidw;
        void (*old)(int);
        int bytes,cnt,status,rc;
        char * bash[2] = {"/bin/bash",0};
        old=signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_DFL);
        rc = pipe(p1); if(rc){perror("pipe()");return -1;}
        rc = pipe(p2); if(rc){perror("pipe()");return -1;}
        pid = fork();
        if (pid<0) { perror("fork"); return -1;}
        if (0 == pid) {
                rc = dup2(p1[0],0); if (-1 == rc) {perror("dup2"); return -1;}
                rc = dup2(p2[1],1); if (-1 == rc) {perror("dup2"); return -1;}
                close(p1[1]); close(p2[0]);
                rc = execvp(bash[0],bash);
                if (-1 == rc) {perror("execvp"); return -1;} exit(-1);
        }
        close(p1[0]);close(p2[1]);
        write(p1[1],work,strlen(work));
        cnt = 0;
        close(p1[1]);
        bytes = read(p2[0],results,so_results);
        while(bytes > 0) {
                cnt+=bytes;
                if (so_results== cnt) break;
                bytes = read(p2[0],results+cnt,so_results-cnt);
        }
        if (cnt == so_results) {
                char dummy[4096];
                bytes = read(p2[0],dummy,4096);
                while (bytes>0) {
                        bytes = read(p2[0],dummy,4096);
                }
        }
        pidw = waitpid(pid,&status,WCONTINUED|WUNTRACED);
        if (pidw != pid || status !=0 ) { perror("waitpid"); return -1;}
        signal(SIGCHLD,old);
        return 0;
}
int main() {
        int rc;
        char buffer[4096];
        rc = plumbing(
"t=$(cat<< @@@\n"
"ICAgICAgIGE4ODg4Yi4KICAgICAgZDg4ODg4OGIuCiAgICAgIDhQIllQIlk4OAogICAgICA4fG98fG98\n"
"ODgKICAgICAgOCcgICAgLjg4CiAgICAgIDhgLl8uJyBZOC4KICAgICBkLyAgICAgIGA4Yi4KICAgIGRQ\n"
"ICAgLiAgICBZOGIuCiAgIGQ4OicgICIgIGA6Ojg4YgogIGQ4IiAgICAgICAgICdZODhiCiA6OFAgICAg\n"
"JyAgICAgIDo4ODgKICA4YS4gICA6ICAgICBfYTg4UAouXy8iWWFhXzogICAufCA4OFB8ClwgICAgWVAi\n"
"ICAgIGB8IDhQICBgLgovICAgICBcLl9fXy5kfCAgICAuJwpgLS0uLl9fKTg4ODhQYC5fLicK\n"
"@@@)\n"
"r64=\'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/\'\n"
"i=0; while [ $i -lt 256 ] ; do tab[$i]=-1 ; let i=$i+1 ;done\n"
"i=0; while [ $i -lt 64 ] ; do tab[`printf \"%d\" \"\'${r64:$i:1}\"`]=$i ; let i=$i+1; done\n"
"bi=0\n"
"i=0 \n"
"while ((i < ${#t} )) \n"
"  do\n"
"   x=${t:$i:1}\n"
"   in=${tab[`printf \"%d\" \"\'$x\"`]}\n"
"   if [ $in -ge 0 ]; then case $bi in\n"
"    0 ) out=$(($in<<2)); bi=6 ;;\n"
"    2 ) out=$(($out|$in)); printf \\\\$(printf \'%03o\' $(($out&255)) ); bi=0 ;;\n"
"    4 ) out=$(($out+($in>>2))); printf \\\\$(printf \'%03o\' $(($out&255)) );\n"
"    bi=0; out=$(($in<<6)); bi=2 ;;\n"
"    * ) out=$(($out+($in>>4))); printf \\\\$(printf \'%03o\' $(($out&255)) );\n"
"    bi=0; out=$(($in<<4)); bi=4 ;;\n"
"    esac fi\n"
"   i=$((1+$i))\n"
"  done\n"
        ,buffer,4096);
        printf("plumbing rc %d\n",rc);
        printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass more arguments to bash, for example bash -o xtrace  , you can change the array declaration from char * bash[2] = {"/bin/bash",0};
to  char * bash[4] = {"/bin/bash","-o","xtrace",0};